# How we can use JDBC connection pooling with AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Can we use JDBC connection pooling with AWS Lambda ? AS AWS lambda function get called on a specific event, so its life time persist even after it finishing one of its call ?

Answer (score 24):

No.  Technically, you could create a connection pool outside of the handler function but since you can only make use of any one single connection per invocation so all you would be doing is tying up database connections and allocating a pool of which you could only ever use 1.

After uploading your Lambda function to AWS, the first time it is invoked AWS will create a container and run the setup code (the code outside of your handler function that creates the pool- let's say N connections) before invoking the handler code.

When the next request arrives, AWS may re-use the container again (or may not. It usually does, but that's down to AWS and not under your control).

Assuming it reuses the container, your handler function will be invoked (the setup code will *not* be run again) and your function would use one of N the connections to your database from the pool (held at the container level).  This is most likely the first connection from the pool, number 1 as it is guaranteed to not be in use, since it's impossible for two functions to run at the same time within the same container.  Read on for an explanation.

If AWS does not reuse the container, it will create a new container and your code will allocate another pool of N connections.  Depending on the turnover of containers, you may exhaust the database pool entirely.

If two requests arrive concurrently, AWS cannot invoke the same handler at the same time. If this were possible, you'd have a shared state problem with the variables defined at the container scope level.  Instead, AWS will use two separate containers and these will both allocate a pool of N connections each, i.e. 2N connections to your database.

It's never necessary for a single invocation function to require more than one connection (unless of course you need to communicate to two independent databases within the same context).

The only time a connection pool would be useful is if it were at one level above the container scope, that is, handed down by the AWS environment itself to the container.  This is not possible.

The best case you can hope for is to have a *single connection per container*.  Even then you would have to manage this single connection to ensure the database server hasn't disconnect or rebooted.  If it does, your container's connection will die and your handler will never be able to connect again (until the container dies), unless you write some code in your function to check for dropped connections.  On a busy server, the container might take a long time to die.

Also keep in mind that if your handler function fails, for example half way through a transaction or having locked a table, the next request invocation will get the dirty connection state from the container.  The first invocation may have opened a transaction and died.  The second invocation may commit and include all the previous queries up to the failure.

I recommend not managing state outside of the handler function at all, unless you have a specific need to optimise.  If you do, then use a single connection, not a pool.

Comment: So is the best approach to use close connections after they are used? And reopen when the next invocation is made? That seems the simplest approach.

Comment: @rharriso That would be my approach. You could leave a single connection open so long as your Lambda function doesn't bail out half way through and leave the connection dirty, for example with a transactional query.

Comment: It's probably still a good idea to use a connection pool of size 1, just so you don't have to manage the logic to test and replace connections.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the lambda is mostly persistent, so JDBC connection pooling should work.  The first time a lambda function is invoked, the environment will be created and it may or may not get reused.  But in practice, subsequent invocations will often reuse the same lambda process along with all program state if your triggering events occur often.

This short lambda function demonstrates this:

```
package test;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class TestLambda implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    private int invocations = 0;

    public String handleRequest(String request, Context context) {
        invocations++;
        System.out.println("invocations = " + invocations);
        return request;
    }
}
```

Invoke this from the AWS console with any string as the test event.  In the CloudWatch logs, you'll see the invocations number increment each time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Its Okay to use BoneCP connection pooling [http://www.jolbox.com/index.html?page=http://www.jolbox.com/jdbc-example.html], the connection pool will persist in frequent invokes of lambda function, if yes then how it can be verified ?

Comment: I haven't tried BoneCP, but I don't see why not.  To verify, configure log4j to log BoneCP at the debug level and examine the logs.

Comment: Thanks, Let me do it, and then update the status here ! perfect :-)

Comment: "subsequent invocations will often reuse the same lambda process" - On this what exactly would be reused ?, Do we have global variables or some other ways that may help us to see whether state of handler maintained even after. I see that on every handler call, its a function, and all of the state of variables finish once the block of got code get executed.  May be Lambda only keep Its own environment variables values.

Comment: Instance variables usually persist across invocations.  I've updated the answer with a short lambda function that demonstrates this.

Comment: Agreed with your answer for instance variables, I tested the example and that worked. but on my case lambda function receives parallel request ( e.g. 20 request per seconds), on that case reusability stuff doesn't work. you may see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523128/how-aws-lambda-container-reuse-works

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is partially incorrect.  Pooling wont work. Two concurrent invocation would cause two containers to be used.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Kudos to the [AWS RDS proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-proxy-now-generally-available/), now you can used pooled `MySql` and `postgrese` connections without any extra configs in your `Java` or other any code specific to AWS Lambda. All you need is to create and `Add a Database proxy` your AWS Lambda function you want to reuse/pool connections. See how-to [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/).

Note: AWS RDS proxy is not included in the Free-Tier ([more here](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/pricing/)).

Comment: If you are running Transaction, this would add a lot of delay with RDS Proxy, Think twice if you have Transaction

Comment: This doesn't seem to support external databases, outside of AWS.

Answer (score 0):

It has caveat
   There is no destroy method which ensures closing pool. One may say DB connection idle time would handle.
   What if same DB being used for other use cases like pool maintain in regular machine Luke EC2. 
  As many say, if there is sudden spike in requests, create chaos to DB as there will be always some maximum connection setting at database side per user.

Comment: canwe not use shutdown hook?

Comment: @ravi Shutdown hook runs only when JVM gets destroyed. So if there is huge load more and more lambdas gets created and all will be active and all try to create connections as there is no central way to control the number of connections.