# Connection pools on AWS lambda

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, lambda, serverless

I have a lambda that is currently deployed on AWS. It is a simple piece of CRUD logic which sits behind a an API gateway.

The problem I am currently facing is that as soon as there is a peak in traffic the connections on my database shoot up.

I understand that this is due to the parallel invocation of many lambdas together, and opening their separate connections, but is there a way I can do some sort of connection pooling here?

The below thread states that I can(If I code a bit intelligently do some sort of a connection pool in a container):

[How we can use JDBC connection pooling with AWS Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415469/how-we-can-use-jdbc-connection-pooling-with-aws-lambda)

But it does not guarantee anything.

Can I do something about this in my lambda or do I **have to** use an external connection pooler for this(I use Postgres, so that should be pg_bouncer)?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, no way round it. You need to use pgBouncer.